# Setting up a pycharm license server

Tags: docker, server, pycharm, archlinux

So I got pycharm professional version. Its well worth it since I'm stuck with Windows atm, and pycharm is amazing, it helps me bypass all of the obstacles I run into wit Windows. The best tool I've come across. So the way I want to do the licensing thing is to create a server which will hold the license.

I want to do this with `Docker`, create a `docker container` which runs the server in the background. So in the tutorial I read, they recommend using `Arch` linux as the linux server to run the license server. So thats what I did. But instead of using bare bones arch, I'm using the security upgraded version. Heres the base image I'm starting from:

```
nning2/compile-linux-grsec
```

So heres my Dockerfile so far:

```
FROM nning2/compile-linux-grsec

ENV APP_ROOT /app
ENV SERVER_DIR /opt/dvt-jb-lic-server
ENV SERVER_BINARY dvt-jb_licsrv.linux.amd64
ENV SERVER_BINARY_PATH "${SERVER_ROOT}/${SERVER_BINARY}"
ENV COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS 1

RUN mkdir -p $APP_ROOT
WORKDIR $APP_ROOT
VOLUME [".:/app"]

ADD "./${SERVER_BINARY}" $APP_ROOT
RUN mkdir -p $SERVER_DIR
RUN cp "${APP_ROOT}/${SERVER_BINARY}" $SERVER_BINARY_PATH
RUN chmod +x $SERVER_BINARY_PATH
RUN ls -l $SERVER_DIR
RUN $SERVER_BINARY_PATH -mode install
```

So now I just need to make the `docker-compose.yml` file to run the license server in the background. Heres what I got so far:

```
version: '2'
    services:
      shell:
        build: .  
        command: /bin/bash service license-server
        ports:
          - "1337:1337"
```

When I run `docker-compose build .`, heres what it outputs:

```
$ docker-compose build --force-rm --no-cache
Building shell
Step 1 : FROM nning2/compile-linux-grsec
 ---> baf47265c7fc
Step 2 : ENV APP_ROOT /app
 ---> Running in 77d33bfe8848
 ---> 67afb97c5b46
Removing intermediate container 77d33bfe8848
Step 3 : ENV SERVER_DIR /opt/dvt-jb-lic-server
 ---> Running in c1b0615d8bec
 ---> 1bc7ac4a8b78
Removing intermediate container c1b0615d8bec
Step 4 : ENV SERVER_BINARY dvt-jb_licsrv.linux.amd64
 ---> Running in be4210954aaa
 ---> ce48dd70acbb
Removing intermediate container be4210954aaa
Step 5 : ENV SERVER_BINARY_PATH "${SERVER_ROOT}/${SERVER_BINARY}"
 ---> Running in 9e1a0aa39855
 ---> a1c99aad2418
Removing intermediate container 9e1a0aa39855
Step 6 : ENV COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS 1
 ---> Running in 2a9337698969
 ---> dae5eff0e382
Removing intermediate container 2a9337698969
Step 7 : RUN mkdir -p $APP_ROOT
 ---> Running in ffe6894f4d15
 ---> 2c9bfd607bc0
Removing intermediate container ffe6894f4d15
Step 8 : WORKDIR $APP_ROOT
 ---> Running in 5404c27b138c
 ---> a607eaed217e
Removing intermediate container 5404c27b138c
Step 9 : VOLUME .:/app
 ---> Running in ad577ac00c9e
 ---> 2fe4a66ba1ed
Removing intermediate container ad577ac00c9e
Step 10 : ADD "./${SERVER_BINARY}" $APP_ROOT
 ---> 5ec55e991fba
Removing intermediate container 55ae3d52227f
Step 11 : RUN mkdir -p $SERVER_DIR
 ---> Running in d76e590f011a
 ---> b379ef02ab88
Removing intermediate container d76e590f011a
Step 12 : RUN cp "${APP_ROOT}/${SERVER_BINARY}" $SERVER_BINARY_PATH
 ---> Running in 5e0d782f4549
 ---> 802eeb561b62
Removing intermediate container 5e0d782f4549
Step 13 : RUN chmod +x $SERVER_BINARY_PATH
 ---> Running in 64c79436824c
 ---> c67396e5a721
Removing intermediate container 64c79436824c
Step 14 : RUN ls -l $SERVER_DIR
 ---> Running in 0cda941ffc29
total 0
 ---> a94136235d9d
Removing intermediate container 0cda941ffc29
Step 15 : RUN $SERVER_BINARY_PATH -mode install
 ---> Running in d9bfeb3ae871
[91m2017/02/05 02:34:38 Installing license server as service.
2017/02/05 02:34:38 open /etc/init.d/JetBrainsLicServerDVT: no such file or directory
2017/02/05 02:34:38 Errors while installing the license server. Are you running this as root/Administrator?
[0m ---> a08092892872
Removing intermediate container d9bfeb3ae871
Successfully built a08092892872
```

So everything goes smoothly until it tries to install the binary. Its not installing the `/etc/init.d/JetBrainsLicServerDVT` file for some reason. I'm new to Arch so don't know how administrator privileges work yet. I seem to have superuser privileges because I can copy the binary to the /opt directory and do various other things that would require superuser privileges.

I'm new to `Arch`, on `Ubuntu` I would use `sudo` but I don't know if that works in Arch. Do I need to install the license server binary file with superuser privileges?

**UPDATE:** I logged into the container interactively to see whats happening. So it looks like this arch distro doesn't even have an `/etc/init.d` directory. So installing this binary doesn't work. But when I just run the binary without any parameters:

```
[root@b140eac75b52 app]# ./dvt-jb_licsrv.linux.amd64
2017/02/05 03:18:50 Starting license server.
2017/02/05 03:18:50

                                 _____    .   +
         _____                   \   |    : ,`
 ________\    |___________________   |____l____ _
/    .        |       |      /___  \_|____/___
\___________\_|\     /`     /   /    |      /y!r
--------------``----\_____/   /\__________/ ------
____\           `~~~~----/    `----------`   /____
\_____/( DVT JetBrains License Server v1.1 )\____/

2017/02/05 03:18:50 [!] Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:1337
2017/02/05 03:18:50 [!] Stop the license server with Ctrl+C
2017/02/05 03:18:50 [?] For advanced usage refer to --help
```

The server runs. I'd prefer to be able to install it properly so I can easily start and restart the service (i.e. with `service start license-server`), but if it works, it works so I can't complain. I don't know why they insist on using arch when it doesn't actually install properly in arch.

So I decided to try creating the `/etc/init.d` directory, then tried installing the binary again, and it worked:

```
[root@b140eac75b52 app]# mkdir /etc/init.d
[root@b140eac75b52 app]# ./dvt-jb_licsrv.linux.amd64 -mode install
2017/02/05 03:41:30 Installing license server as service.
2017/02/05 03:41:30 Successfully installed license server service.
```

And to make fully sure its working:

```
[root@b140eac75b52 app]# /etc/init.d/JetBrainsLicServerDVT restart
Stopping JetBrainsLicServerDVT..
Stopped
Starting JetBrainsLicServerDVT
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I thought this was the solution, but turns out its not. Firstly I can't run the container with `/etc/init.d/license_server start` in the docker-compose.yml for some reason. When I check for running containers with `docker ps`, there are no running containers. I can run the container with `/bin/bash` by itself, and according to kitematic, the container is running and it should be accessible through the forwarded port:
https://i.gyazo.com/1de96b014cfbc78f4c188ec33f336519.png

But if I ping that IP and port, I get:

> Ping request could not find host 192.168.99.100:1337. Please check the
>   name and try again.

I'm using Docker with VirtualBox, and no forwarded ports show up for the VM. I tried adding them manual but that changed nothing.

The problem was that the `/etc/init.d` folder didn't exist. So to fix it, I just created the folder, now the binary installs properly:

```
[root@b140eac75b52 app]# mkdir /etc/init.d
[root@b140eac75b52 app]# ./dvt-jb_licsrv.linux.amd64 -mode install
2017/02/05 03:41:30 Installing license server as service.
2017/02/05 03:41:30 Successfully installed license server service.
```

and now I can start, stop and restart the server easily:

```
[root@b140eac75b52 app]# /etc/init.d/JetBrainsLicServerDVT restart
Stopping JetBrainsLicServerDVT..
Stopped
Starting JetBrainsLicServerDVT
```

So the improved `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM nning2/compile-linux-grsec

ENV APP_ROOT /app
ENV SERVER_DIR /opt/dvt-jb-lic-server
ENV SERVER_BINARY dvt-jb_licsrv.linux.amd64
ENV SERVER_BINARY_PATH "${SERVER_ROOT}/${SERVER_BINARY}"
ENV COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS 1

RUN mkdir -p $APP_ROOT
WORKDIR $APP_ROOT
VOLUME [".:/app"]

ADD "./${SERVER_BINARY}" $APP_ROOT
RUN mkdir -p $SERVER_DIR
RUN mv "${APP_ROOT}/${SERVER_BINARY}" $SERVER_BINARY_PATH
RUN chmod +x $SERVER_BINARY_PATH
RUN mkdir /etc/init.d
RUN $SERVER_BINARY_PATH -mode install
RUN mv "/etc/init.d/${SERVER_BINARY}" /etc/init.d/pycharm_license
```

and the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  license_server:
    environment: 
      ENV COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS: 1
    build: .  
    command: /bin/bash /etc/init.d/pycharm_license start
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
```

NOTE: I changed the `/etc/init.d` command name to something a bit easier to remember.

NOTE2: I'm new to Docker. I'd like to add this to the Docker hub since I spent a bit of time making it. But there are lots of things I don't know yet, like how to let users input configuration parameters (i.e. different users will need a different binary file).

If anyone wants to turn this into a Docker image and put it up on the hub, feel free to do so. I uploaded the `gist` here:
https://gist.github.com/entheologist/42a6f6bb305897b16d1d1d6c4a9d7360

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to install it. You can just run it from ENTRYPOINT

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  license_server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 1337

ADD ./dvt-jb_licsrv.linux.amd64 /app
RUN chmod +x /app/dvt-jb_licsrv.linux.amd64

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/dvt-jb_licsrv.linux.amd64"]
```